# Decimal to RGB in Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, decimal, rgb

I am trying to convert a decimal value back to an RGB value.

Assuming that this is the formula for compiling the decimal value

```
c = r*(255*255)+g*255+b
```

(For example rgb(16,120,78) adds up to 1071078)

How would one solve r, g and b without any "overflow"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: r = x, g = ff is always encoded the same as r = x + 1, g = 0.

Comment: Likewise if b is 255, setting it to 0 and adding 1 to g obtains the same encoding. Use 256.

Answer (score 12):

Use division, modulo (`%`) and floor rounding:

```
var r = Math.floor(c / (256*256));
var g = Math.floor(c / 256) % 256;
var b = c % 256;
```

#### Edit:

halex spotted the diffence in use of 255 and 256 in the code. You should (as Millie Smith pointed out) use 256 instead of 255 when you put the components together:

```
var c = r * (256*256) + g * 256 + b;
```

A color component can have a value from 0 to 255, so you need to multiply by 256 to keep the next component from overlapping the previous.

Comment: I think you want to divide by 255 instead of 256. Assume the original color is rgb(20,0,0) that will become c=1300500 and with your formula you will get r=19 instead of 20. But OP should use 256 in his calculation so in an indirect way you are right :)

Comment: @halex OP needs to adjust their formula to use 256. Right now, multiple RGB values can encode to the same values.

Comment: Thanks @halex I noticed that too, I have been getting really wonky results with that formula. This solution works pretty well provided that I correct my decimal formula.

Comment: @halex: Thanks for spotting the difference, I used 256 without checking the OP's code closely enough. However, 256 is the correct value for this, as Millie Smith pointed out, and I should of course have added a note about this if I had seen it.

Answer (score 3):

This [Github link](https://gist.github.com/callumlocke/41b210743990f07c2d96) helps a lot, but I edited the code with this code to solve a problem with me:

```
// convert three r,g,b integers (each 0-255) to a single decimal integer (something 
between 0 and ~16m)
function colourToNumber(r, g, b) {
 return (r << 16) + (g << 8) + (b);
}

// convert it back again (to a string)
function numberToColour(number) {
 const r = (number & 0xff0000) >> 16;
 const g = (number & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
 const b = (number & 0x0000ff);

 //return [b, g, r];
 return `rgb(${b},${g},${r})`;
}
```

my edited code make the RGB returns correctly like the color I set

Examples of mine:

**color in decimal is: 11665407**
*this is yellow*

**color in decimal is: 11665329**
*this is green*

please test booth codes with this example:
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bkwcfl)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your formula for computing the decimal value looks off. 255 isn't a power of 16 (or even 2); if you want to shift a hex digit left, like what multiplying by powers of 10 does under decimal, you want to multiply by 16^n, where n is the number of places to shift it left.

Here's our new RGB to decimal formula:

```
c = r * 16^4 + g * 16^2 + b
```

So, supposing we have *c*, the decimal representation of an RGB color code, we solve for *r*, *g*, *b*:

```
b = c % 256
g_0 = (c % 65536 - b)
r_0 = c - g_0 - b
g = g_0 / 256
r = r_0 / 65536
```

These are all integer operations, so they should be fast, but I can't assure you the interpreter will handle them that way. As a function:

```
function c_to_rgb(c) {
    var b = c % 256,
        g_0 = (c % 65536 - b),
        r_0 = c - g_0 - b,
        g = g_0 / 256,
        r = r_0 / 65536;

    return [r, g, b];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I managed to solve it that way

getRGBFromDecimal(number) {
    var b = Math.floor(number / (256*256));
    var g = Math.floor(number / 256) % 256;
    var r = number % 256;

    return `RGB(${r},${g},${b})`;
}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how this code works, as it may be helpful to others.

Comment: "red" is encoded in the last significant bits?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.