# How to convert an Integer to Red, Green, and Blue values

Tags: c#, integer, rgb

I'm converting an RGB value to a single integer with the following:

```
public static int RGBtoInt(int red, int greed, int blue)
{
    return blue + green + (green * 255) + (red * 65536);
}
```

but struggling to write an inverse method taking in an integer and returning the single RGB components.

Something of thematic nature with:

```
public static Vector3 IntToRgb(int value)
{
    // calculations...
    return new Vector3(red, green, blue); 
}
```

The `Color.FromArgb(int)` method isn't creating the RGB colour I need.

The `RGBtoInt` function above matches the RGB integer values returned by OpenGL and I am looking for a reverse method. It's the same conversion method used [here](https://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html).

Comment: Unless you're trying to avoid a `System.Drawing` dependency, just use `Color.FromArgb()` and `Color.ToArgb()`. No need to write your own.

Comment: Note that your `RGBtoInt()` method appears to be incorrect. It looks like it should be `return b + (g * 255) + (r * 65536);`

Comment: "The Color.FromArgb(int) method isn't creating the RGB colour I need." - perhaps this is because of the bug in your `RGBtoInt()`?

Comment: I need it to match the integer colour values returned by OpenGL which are coming back in that format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241442/decimal-to-rgb-in-javascript-and-php

Comment: I thought RGB values in OpenGL were floats between 0.0f and 1.0f?

Comment: Correct they are, but converting between the 0-255 and 0-1 range is trivial. I thought it would simplify the question by not mentioning it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The conversion can be done as follows.

```
public static Vector3 IntToRgb(int value)
{
    var red =   ( value >>  0 ) & 255;
    var green = ( value >>  8 ) & 255;
    var blue =  ( value >> 16 ) & 255;
    return new Vector3(red, green, blue); 
}
```

To my understanding, the initial conversion should be done as follows.

```
public static int RGBtoInt(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return ( r << 0 ) | ( g << 8 ) | ( b << 16 );
}
```

Comment: However, if some methods provided by some API are available, these are to be preferred, I think.

Comment: initial conversion should be `( r >> 0 ) | ( g >> 8 ) | ( b >> 16 );` (please, notice `|` instead of '&')

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the comment, I mixed them up.

Comment: I've actually solved the main problem via an alternate route, by changing the format in which OpenGL returns the pixel data, from `PixelFormat.Rgb` to `PixelFormat.Bgr`. In any case, although this doesn't technically answer my question (by inversing my formula), I've accepted it on the basis of being informative.

Comment: The shifts in the initial conversion should be going left, not right.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `Color c = Color.FromArgb(someInt);`
and then use `c.R`, `c.G` and `c.B` for Red, Green and Blue values respectively